# G-suite business mail sending quota

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-workspace

I used the trail version of G-Suite business. I have pasted a script for checking the email quota in google sheet.
When I run the script, it shows only 100 instead of 500 quota. I asked google about that and they said it should be 500 but what I got is only 100. 
How could I know the real number of the quota?

```
function checking(){
  var emailQuotaRemaining = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
  Logger.log("Remaining email quota: " + emailQuotaRemaining);
  MailApp.sendEmail('xxxxxx@xxx.com(my email)',"My Subject", "Raw Log:\n------------------\n" + Logger.getLog());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the expected amount.

[getRemainingDailyQuota()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#getRemainingDailyQuota()):

Returns the number of remaining emails a user can send for the rest of the day.
Quotas are based on the number of email recipients.

And looking at [Apps Script quota](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas), 100/day is allocated for email recipients day.

[image]